# Reverse chronological view of any responses to my posts/comments?

Tags: support, recent-activity, sorting

Is there a way of getting a view (that I can bookmark) of a reverse chronological sort of any responses to my posts/comments?

I'm getting a bit confused between the various views available, but I haven't seen anything (could have missed something) that addresses my requirement above.

Comment: I'm interested in an answer for this myself

Answer (score 1):

I deal with this in one of three ways:

1. If it is a comment or answer to a post I've made, it will show up in my Recent Activity (Click on the Envelope, then Responses, then Today).
2. If it is not a comment or answer to one of my posts, I will favorite the question (by clicking on the star); I can then return to it by clicking on my name, then Favorites, then Newest.
3. OR I will just leave the question open in another browser window, and come back to it later and refresh it.  After an hour or two, the question gets stale anyway, and I can close the window.